# Is there a hidden rabbit hole in returning in try block?

Tags: c++, exception

So to be more specific, here is the example I got:

Example 1.

```
std::vector<std::string> f()
{
    try 
    {
        return someOtherFunction();
    }
    catch (...) 
    {
        std::vector<std::string> res;
        ///...
        return res;
    }
}
```

Example 2.

```
std::vector<std::string> f()
{
    try 
    {
        auto res = someOtherFunction();
        return res;
    }
    catch (...) 
    {
        std::vector<std::string> res;
        ///...
        return res;
    }
}
```

Are these 2 examples equivalent?
In other words, is there a case when the befaviour ot the program can be different on different examples?

Comment: It is possible to write a class with two different conversion operators to `vector<string>`, one callable on an lvalue and the other on an rvalue. `someOtherFunction()` could be returning an instance of that class, and then the two fragments would call different conversion operators. This has nothing to do with exceptions though.

Comment: Is there something you suspect?  Or are you generating all C++ code and asking "is there a hidden rabbit hole here"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `return expression` and that expression is an rvalue, in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) the elision of that expression into the return value is required.

When you `return local_variable`, the elision is **not** guaranteed, and the local variable and the return value can have separate identities, depending on optimization levels and compiler flags or something else.

If `res` is not a `std::vector<string>`, then the two cases are quite different, in that one is converting from an rvalue and the other from an lvalue, as @igor noticed.

Assuming `res` is an lvalue of type `std::vector<std::string>`:

If an exception is thrown in `someOtherFunction` during the construction of the vector, the first thing that happens is that any parts of that object completed are destroyed.  Then we enter the catch.  It is possible that your compiler might decide to elide the `res` object in the `try` block into the return value conditional on what happens in the `try` block; compilers are free to choose to elide or not in that NRVO case based on whatever rules they want.  I see no reason why your compiler could not elide there, however, as by the time the block enters the return value (even if elided into) had to have been destroyed.

---

If this was a puzzle, I could make the two cases behave differently in near arbitrary ways.  If it was code written in a non-hostile way, I would reasonably assume they are identical in behavior.  If a bug shows up there, I'd examine it for the hostile corner cases.

But most of the hostile corner cases have nothing to do with `try`, only a possible compiler decision to change elision rules based off of what happens in `catch`; however, that is something I don't think is likely.  And even if you did change elision rules, it wouldn't be likely to make any difference, as `std::vector`'s move constructor and `std::vector` being elided are nearly indistinguishable anyhow.